# Sending email to Salesforce Community User through Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to send email to Community Users whenever they are created or updated. I don't want to use Community (available in salesforce data source) since I can't add entry criteria there. 
In my journey, I've used 'User' as a Salesforce Object and added the criteria's I want. When I tried to test the journey by updating the Community user it was not evaluated in the journey, however when I updated a usual User record which matched the criteria, it was taken in the journey. So, the Journey is somehow ignoring the Community Users and taking in the actual user records.
How can I make Journey consider Community Users too?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This article:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_jb_objects_ref.htm&type=5

leads me to believe that you have to listen to the Object "networkMember", not "user". You should then be able to inject the associated user record into the journey.

The NetworkMember object represents the user as a member of the community:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_networkmember.htm

> NetworkMember
>
> Represents a member of a community. Members can be either users in your company or external users with portal profiles.

Can you try this approach?

Comment: Thank you Jonas. I did tried it, however Journey did not evaluated the record.
Below are fields and object details used in Journey, let me know if anything is wrong:
WHO
Member ID (User)
OBJECT
NetworkMember
ACTION
Created;Updated;
CRITERIA
NetworkMember:MemberId WASSET AND NetworkMember:NetworkId WASSET
RELATED OBJECTS CRITERIA
Member:User:User_Zone__c EQUALS EU OR Member:User:Country__c EQUALS TH
ENTRY DATA
NetworkMember:Member:Email; NetworkMember:Member:Id; NetworkMember:Member:Name; NetworkMember:Id;